# Flowable create user defined tables with mysql using datasource configuration & springboot

Tags: java, mysql, sqldatasource, activiti, bpmn

I am trying flowable with springboot and when I include flowable engine in maven dependency it creates tables required for flowable.

But am unable to create a user defined table to insert/update values. I don't want to use property files as it overrides the default datasource configuration manager.

I could not see a good example in flowable docs for the above. Any examples to try the above one out ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are describing. You can easily create tables or do pretty much anything you want by adding an initializingBean (Spring InitializingBean) to the application class.

Comment: Harley I am following the code as described here in https://github.com/jbarrez/spring-boot-activiti-example but i am kicking a process from BPMN2 xml and i get the error in :

    Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        personRepository.save(new Person("vikramtnj", "Vikram", "Swaminathan"));
    }

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException. 

In short am getting NullPointerException when i autowire the fields inside the javaDelegate. Can you help me on this

Comment: Hard to know whats going on with the details you have provided. Feel free to point me at the github repo or provide a test environment.

Comment: It works when used from the java Layer but the Process XML Configuration calls a Java Service Task and the XML File does not Autowire the  @Autowired private PersonRepository personRepository. Any way to include the field in BPMN Process XML Configuration too